# Variable scope within foreach-object in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, variables, scope

I am trying to understand the output & error message for:

```
# declare empty array
$thisDataArray = @()
# assign array values
$thisDataArray = '123','cadabra','456','789','trouble'
# declare empty array to receive specific values
$letters = @()
# use this pattern to filter array members that contain letters
$regex = "[a-z]"

# confirm the array values
Write-Host $thisDataArray
# pipe array & filter to find the values
$thisDataArray | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regex -CaseSensitive | ForEach-Object { $letters = $_.Matches.Value} 
# output the result
Write-Host $letters
```

The error is: The variable `$letters` is assigned but never used. And the output is:

```
123 cadabra 456 789 trouble
t r o u b l e
```

My questions are:

1. How is `Write-Host $letters` not using the assigned variable `$letters`?
2. Why do I only get the one array member 'trouble' from my `$regex`?
3. And finally. Why are there spaces between the chars of trouble e.g 't r o u b l e'

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How is `Write-Host $letters` not using the assigned variable `$letters?`

Because it is outside the `ForEach-Object` loop, hence, you're only reading the last result from that variable assignment. You probably wanted:

```
$thisDataArray | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regex -CaseSensitive | ForEach-Object {
    $letters = $_.Matches.Value
    Write-Host $letters
}
```

Though, is worth noting that output to console is implicit unless captured or redirected, so, `Write-Host` might not be needed nor is a variable assignment:

```
$thisDataArray | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regex -CaseSensitive | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches.Value
}
```

> 2. Why do I only get the one array member 'trouble' from my `$regex`?

You don't, you would get `cadabra` and `trouble` assuming [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2) is inside the loop.

> 3. And finally. Why are there spaces between the chars of trouble e.g `t r o u b l e`

Because your [regex `[a-z]` matches a single character](https://regex101.com/r/Opgqqd/1) and since `-AllMatches` is being used, all appeareances of a character match are being outputted. The reason why they then appear concatenated by a space is because `Write-Host` is stringifying the `$letters` array and joining it by [`$OFS` (default `$OFS` is a space)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#ofs). i.e.:

```
PS ..\pwsh> $letters      
t
r
o
u
b
l
e

PS ..\pwsh> Write-Host $letters
t r o u b l e

PS ..\pwsh> [string] $letters
t r o u b l e

PS ..\pwsh> $ofs = ''
PS ..\pwsh> [string] $letters
trouble
```

- If you want to match **all letters from `a` to `z`** you could use:

```
$regex = "[a-z]+"
```

- If you want to match those elements `$thisDataArray` **which have only letters from `a` to `z`** then you could use:

```
$regex = "^[a-z]+$"
```

As for the "error" *The variable `$letters` is assigned but never used*, I assume you're referring to a [PSScriptAnalyzer Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscriptanalyzer/?view=ps-modules), namely [**UseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/usedeclaredvarsmorethanassignments?view=ps-modules), which simply means, that the variable being assigned inside a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) (`ForEach-Object -Process { ... }` in this case) is never used inside that script block:

[image]